# Is the "imagesource" tag useful?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are 98 questions tagged with [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource), but its use seems to be a complete mess.

After reading some initial responses and looking into actual posts further, it seems that two major groups consist of dealing with .NET's `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` class and, basically, any use of `src` attriubute on `img` tag in HTML/DOM. IMO, first use should be retagged to something like [.net-imagesource](/questions/tagged/.net-imagesource), and second group should have this tag removed, because `src` is not specific to `img` and this tag basically serves no purposes in those questions.

What little posts remains should lose this tag too and, possibly, have more appropriate tags assigned to them.

Comment: You tell us.  Is there anything salvageable from the use of the tag?

Comment: I see 98 questions, is this typo or do you mean questions with that tag plus something else you didn't mention yet? Anyway, if the tag was added just because the question is referring somehow to source of some image I think it can be edited out.

Comment: @ChrisGerken, "its use seems to be a complete mess". Check answers below, they talk about completely different cases.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, now I see them too. First few hours when I posted this I've seen only exactly 9.

Comment: Probably because you were in the [faq tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagesource?sort=faq&pagesize=50) of the tag.. always make sure to go to the [active tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagesource?sort=active&pagesize=50) to see all.

Answer (score 5):

[Some of those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+imagesource) are using the tag referring to the .NET `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` class. Those are 24 questions out of 98.

There could be other frameworks that define an `ImageSource` class, or where `imagesource()` is a function.

For the other questions, the tag should probably be removed.

At least in the first case, the tag is helpful. I would rather not unconditionally remove it from every question using it.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful a tag for "any class or method named 'ImageSource'" would be.  However, if it is indeed primarily used to refer to a particular class from a particular framework, it could be pruned down to only those questions and documented as only applying to it.

Comment: What platform or framework is this class from?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` is defined in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

41 questions are tagged with both [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+imagesource

And as kiamlaluno noted, 24 questions are tagged with both [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+imagesource

The union of these seems to represent the set of [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource) tagged questions referring to the `ImageSource` class within the .NET framework. They don't intersect on all questions, so the total number of relevant questions is a little under 50 (a quick count was 7 [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource) questions which looked relevant to `ImageSource` that were not tagged with [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) as well).

The rest did look like a mix of questions either related to the `src` attribute of the html element `img` or some other concept semantically related to the sourcing of an image in some form, sometimes with no other direct reference to "source" other than the use of the tag. I think I saw only one [imagesource](/questions/tagged/imagesource) tagged question which referred to an class or class member named ImageSource which wasn't tagged C# or wpf, but it ended up [being about winphone7 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939924/programmatically-set-the-background-of-a-button-to-be-an-image), and so still referring to the .NET class of `ImageSource`.

I would agree that either the tag should be renamed to `.net-imagesource` or it should at least be definitionally specified as referring to the .NET `ImageSource` class, and questions using the tag in other ways should have it pruned. Because the tag is currently used somewhat ambiguously, I'm not comfortable editing it myself to define it as being for the .NET usage specifically, but I do feel that would be the most useful solution.

Answer (score -2):

no, it should not be removed, image sourcery is a fundamental and evident feature for webdevelepent and even more - the point is imo that many users dont tag their imagesource related questions with it because they think in their language pattern like php or ruby and tag their questions like this and not on that meta layer 'image sourcery'

Comment: "image sourcery" - Can't tell if joking or really seriously believes... /meme